# Throw error on bad import or require

Tags: javascript, browserify

When importing a module (*using commonJS `require` or ES6 `import`*), **browserify** will throw when the module doesn't exist (*wrong path*), but it doesn't do anything when the required property does not exist.

As an example

```
// vars.js
export const VAR1 = "var1";
export const VAR2 = "var2";

// app.js
import {VAR1} from "./vars.js";
import {VAR3} from "./vars.js";  // -> doesn't exist (undefined)
```

Is there a way to stop browserify or throw an error when an imported module property doesn't exist?
This can be part of a build step, I don't mind.

Comment: AFAIK, browserify doesn't know anything about ES6 modules, so it couldn't do anything about. Consider using another bundler which does understand ES6 modules, or use a linter (not sure if eslint has a plugin for that).

Comment: mostly use CommonJS modules (`module.export` and `require`) which browserify understand fine. My example is with ES6 just for clarity and brevity.

Comment: Doing this with CommonJS is even more difficult because exports can be dynamically defined (i.e. at runtime).